# Combine bib files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Given several .bib files `ref1.bib,ref2.bib,ref3.bib,...` and a latex document which uses a subset of the references from all the .bib files via `\bibliography{ref1,ref2,ref3,...}`, I would like to generate a new .bib file `combined_ref.bib` which contains the original bibtex entries of all references that are cited in the latex document.

I am aware of the .bbl file, but it outputs a formatted list of references. I want basically a similar file but with the original bibtex entries.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please tell us which front-end editor you use. Depending on the editor, some built-in resources may be readily available to help you achieve your formatting objective.

Comment: @Mico using TeXstudio

Answer (score 0):

You could use Zotero (or any other similar program) to import all your .bib files, and then export the full library.

I personally haven't tried this, but sounds possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is either going in the wrong direction (OP wants to do more than just merge) or (as written) going to be very manual (would require manually identifying and selecting all cited papers from within Zotero)